# WxPython demo code- passing a logger object

Tags: wxpython

Im trying few WXpython demo code in my machine... Just trying to understand how do I pass the logger object...Should it be just the logger object, or can I pass a file name to write to the file..

Here is my modified code...

```
import wx, wx.lib.customtreectrl, wx.gizmos
try:
    import treemixin 
except ImportError:
    from wx.lib.mixins import treemixin

overview = treemixin.__doc__

class TreeModel(object):
    ''' TreeModel holds the domain objects that are shown in the different
    tree controls. Each domain object is simply a two-tuple consisting of
    a label and a list of child tuples, i.e. (label, [list of child tuples]). 
    '''
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.items = []
        self.itemCounter = 0
        super(TreeModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def GetItem(self, indices):
        text, children = 'Hidden root', self.items
        for index in indices:
            text, children = children[index]
        return text, children

    def GetText(self, indices):
        return self.GetItem(indices)[0]

    def GetChildren(self, indices):
        return self.GetItem(indices)[1]

    def GetChildrenCount(self, indices):
        return len(self.GetChildren(indices))

    def SetChildrenCount(self, indices, count):
        children = self.GetChildren(indices)
        while len(children) > count:
            children.pop()
        while len(children) < count:
            children.append(('item %d'%self.itemCounter, []))
            self.itemCounter += 1

    def MoveItem(self, itemToMoveIndex, newParentIndex):
        itemToMove = self.GetItem(itemToMoveIndex)
        newParentChildren = self.GetChildren(newParentIndex)
        newParentChildren.append(itemToMove)
        oldParentChildren = self.GetChildren(itemToMoveIndex[:-1])
        oldParentChildren.remove(itemToMove)


class DemoTreeMixin(treemixin.VirtualTree, treemixin.DragAndDrop, 
                    treemixin.ExpansionState):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.model = kwargs.pop('treemodel')
#         self.log = kwargs.pop('log')
        super(DemoTreeMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.CreateImageList()

    def CreateImageList(self):
        size = (16, 16)
        self.imageList = wx.ImageList(*size)
        for art in wx.ART_FOLDER, wx.ART_FILE_OPEN, wx.ART_NORMAL_FILE:
            self.imageList.Add(wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(art, wx.ART_OTHER, 
                                                        size))
        self.AssignImageList(self.imageList)

    def OnGetItemText(self, indices):
        return self.model.GetText(indices)

    def OnGetChildrenCount(self, indices):
        return self.model.GetChildrenCount(indices)

    def OnGetItemFont(self, indices):
        # Show how to change the item font. Here we use a small font for
        # items that have children and the default font otherwise.
        if self.model.GetChildrenCount(indices) > 0:
            return wx.SMALL_FONT
        else:
            return super(DemoTreeMixin, self).OnGetItemFont(indices)

    def OnGetItemTextColour(self, indices):
        # Show how to change the item text colour. In this case second level
        # items are coloured red and third level items are blue. All other
        # items have the default text colour.
        if len(indices) % 2 == 0:
            return wx.RED
        elif len(indices) % 3 == 0:
            return wx.BLUE
        else:
            return super(DemoTreeMixin, self).OnGetItemTextColour(indices)

    def OnGetItemBackgroundColour(self, indices):
        # Show how to change the item background colour. In this case the
        # background colour of each third item is green.
        if indices[-1] == 2:
            return wx.GREEN
        else: 
            return super(DemoTreeMixin, 
                         self).OnGetItemBackgroundColour(indices)

    def OnGetItemImage(self, indices, which):
        # Return the right icon depending on whether the item has children.
        if which in [wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal, wx.TreeItemIcon_Selected]:
            if self.model.GetChildrenCount(indices):
                return 0
            else:
                return 2
        else:
            return 1

    def OnDrop(self, dropTarget, dragItem):
        dropIndex = self.GetIndexOfItem(dropTarget)
        dropText = self.model.GetText(dropIndex)
        dragIndex = self.GetIndexOfItem(dragItem)
        dragText = self.model.GetText(dragIndex)
#         self.log.write('drop %s %s on %s %s'%(dragText, dragIndex,
#             dropText, dropIndex))
        self.model.MoveItem(dragIndex, dropIndex)
        self.GetParent().RefreshItems()


class VirtualTreeCtrl(DemoTreeMixin, wx.TreeCtrl):
    pass


class VirtualTreeListCtrl(DemoTreeMixin, wx.gizmos.TreeListCtrl):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['style'] = wx.TR_DEFAULT_STYLE | wx.TR_FULL_ROW_HIGHLIGHT
        super(VirtualTreeListCtrl, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.AddColumn('Column 0')
        self.AddColumn('Column 1')
        for art in wx.ART_TIP, wx.ART_WARNING:
            self.imageList.Add(wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(art, wx.ART_OTHER, 
                                                        (16, 16)))

    def OnGetItemText(self, indices, column=0):
        # Return a different label depending on column.
        return '%s, column %d'%\
            (super(VirtualTreeListCtrl, self).OnGetItemText(indices), column)

    def OnGetItemImage(self, indices, which, column=0):
        # Also change the image of the other columns when the item has 
        # children.
        if column == 0:
            return super(VirtualTreeListCtrl, self).OnGetItemImage(indices, 
                                                                   which)
        elif self.OnGetChildrenCount(indices):
            return 4
        else:
            return 3


class VirtualCustomTreeCtrl(DemoTreeMixin, 
                            wx.lib.customtreectrl.CustomTreeCtrl):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.checked = {}
        kwargs['style'] = wx.TR_HIDE_ROOT | \
            wx.TR_HAS_BUTTONS | wx.TR_FULL_ROW_HIGHLIGHT
        super(VirtualCustomTreeCtrl, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.Bind(wx.lib.customtreectrl.EVT_TREE_ITEM_CHECKED,
                  self.OnItemChecked)

    def OnGetItemType(self, indices):
        if len(indices) == 1:
            return 1
        elif len(indices) == 2:
            return 2
        else:
            return 0

    def OnGetItemChecked(self, indices):
        return self.checked.get(indices, False)

    def OnItemChecked(self, event):
        item = event.GetItem()
        itemIndex = self.GetIndexOfItem(item)
        if self.GetItemType(item) == 2: 
            # It's a radio item; reset other items on the same level
            for nr in range(self.GetChildrenCount(self.GetItemParent(item))):
                self.checked[itemIndex[:-1]+(nr,)] = False
        self.checked[itemIndex] = True



class TreeNotebook(wx.Notebook):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        treemodel = kwargs.pop('treemodel')
#         log = kwargs.pop('log')
        super(TreeNotebook, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.trees = []
        for class_, title in [(VirtualTreeCtrl, 'TreeCtrl'),
                              (VirtualTreeListCtrl, 'TreeListCtrl'),
                              (VirtualCustomTreeCtrl, 'CustomTreeCtrl')]:
#             tree = class_(self, treemodel=treemodel, log=log)
            tree = class_(self, treemodel=treemodel)
            self.trees.append(tree)
            self.AddPage(tree, title)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED, self.OnPageChanged)

    def OnPageChanged(self, event):
        oldTree = self.GetPage(event.OldSelection)
        newTree = self.GetPage(event.Selection)
        newTree.RefreshItems()
        newTree.SetExpansionState(oldTree.GetExpansionState())
        event.Skip()

    def GetIndicesOfSelectedItems(self):
        tree = self.trees[self.GetSelection()]
        if tree.GetSelections():
            return [tree.GetIndexOfItem(item) for item in tree.GetSelections()]
        else:
            return [()]

    def RefreshItems(self):
        tree = self.trees[self.GetSelection()]
        tree.RefreshItems()
        tree.UnselectAll()


class TestPanel(wx.App):
#     def __init__(self, parent, log):
#         self.log = log
#         super(TestPanel, self).__init__(parent)
    def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)
        self.frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, title='My Title')
#         self.log = log
        self.treemodel = TreeModel()
        self.CreateControls()
        self.LayoutControls()

    def CreateControls(self):
        self.notebook = TreeNotebook(self, treemodel=self.treemodel) 
#log=self.log)
        self.label = wx.StaticText(self, label='Number of children: ')
        self.childrenCountCtrl = wx.SpinCtrl(self, value='0', max=10000)
        self.button = wx.Button(self, label='Update children')
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnEnter)

    def LayoutControls(self):
        hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        options = dict(flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, border=2)
        hSizer.Add(self.label, **options)
        hSizer.Add(self.childrenCountCtrl, 2, **options)
        hSizer.Add(self.button, **options)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.notebook, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(hSizer, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnEnter(self, event):
        indicesList = self.notebook.GetIndicesOfSelectedItems()
        newChildrenCount = self.childrenCountCtrl.GetValue()
        for indices in indicesList:
            text = self.treemodel.GetText(indices)
            oldChildrenCount = self.treemodel.GetChildrenCount(indices)
#             self.log.write('%s %s now has %d children (was %d)'%(text, indices,
#                 newChildrenCount, oldChildrenCount))
            self.treemodel.SetChildrenCount(indices, newChildrenCount)
        self.notebook.RefreshItems()


# def runTest(frame, nb, log):
#     win = TestPanel(nb, log)
#     return win
# 
# 
# if __name__ == '__main__':
#     import sys, os, run
#     run.main(['', os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])] + sys.argv[1:])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = TestPanel()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to include the log parameter. That is for redirecting to the "log" window (i.e. a multiline TextBox) in the demo. You should just remove the references to it. See also http://wiki.wxpython.org/Using%20wxPython%20Demo%20Code

EDIT: The code has bad parenting going on. You are passing the wx.App object as the parent to all the widgets. This is a big no-no! You should be passing a wx.Panel object to them as their parent. I have edited your code a bit below:

```
import wx, wx.lib.customtreectrl, wx.gizmos
try:
    import treemixin 
except ImportError:
    from wx.lib.mixins import treemixin

overview = treemixin.__doc__

class TreeModel(object):
    ''' TreeModel holds the domain objects that are shown in the different
    tree controls. Each domain object is simply a two-tuple consisting of
    a label and a list of child tuples, i.e. (label, [list of child tuples]). 
    '''
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.items = []
        self.itemCounter = 0
        super(TreeModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def GetItem(self, indices):
        text, children = 'Hidden root', self.items
        for index in indices:
            text, children = children[index]
        return text, children

    def GetText(self, indices):
        return self.GetItem(indices)[0]

    def GetChildren(self, indices):
        return self.GetItem(indices)[1]

    def GetChildrenCount(self, indices):
        return len(self.GetChildren(indices))

    def SetChildrenCount(self, indices, count):
        children = self.GetChildren(indices)
        while len(children) > count:
            children.pop()
        while len(children) < count:
            children.append(('item %d'%self.itemCounter, []))
            self.itemCounter += 1

    def MoveItem(self, itemToMoveIndex, newParentIndex):
        itemToMove = self.GetItem(itemToMoveIndex)
        newParentChildren = self.GetChildren(newParentIndex)
        newParentChildren.append(itemToMove)
        oldParentChildren = self.GetChildren(itemToMoveIndex[:-1])
        oldParentChildren.remove(itemToMove)


class DemoTreeMixin(treemixin.VirtualTree, treemixin.DragAndDrop, 
                    treemixin.ExpansionState):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.model = kwargs.pop('treemodel')
#         self.log = kwargs.pop('log')
        super(DemoTreeMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.CreateImageList()

    def CreateImageList(self):
        size = (16, 16)
        self.imageList = wx.ImageList(*size)
        for art in wx.ART_FOLDER, wx.ART_FILE_OPEN, wx.ART_NORMAL_FILE:
            self.imageList.Add(wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(art, wx.ART_OTHER, 
                                                        size))
        self.AssignImageList(self.imageList)

    def OnGetItemText(self, indices):
        return self.model.GetText(indices)

    def OnGetChildrenCount(self, indices):
        return self.model.GetChildrenCount(indices)

    def OnGetItemFont(self, indices):
        # Show how to change the item font. Here we use a small font for
        # items that have children and the default font otherwise.
        if self.model.GetChildrenCount(indices) > 0:
            return wx.SMALL_FONT
        else:
            return super(DemoTreeMixin, self).OnGetItemFont(indices)

    def OnGetItemTextColour(self, indices):
        # Show how to change the item text colour. In this case second level
        # items are coloured red and third level items are blue. All other
        # items have the default text colour.
        if len(indices) % 2 == 0:
            return wx.RED
        elif len(indices) % 3 == 0:
            return wx.BLUE
        else:
            return super(DemoTreeMixin, self).OnGetItemTextColour(indices)

    def OnGetItemBackgroundColour(self, indices):
        # Show how to change the item background colour. In this case the
        # background colour of each third item is green.
        if indices[-1] == 2:
            return wx.GREEN
        else: 
            return super(DemoTreeMixin, 
                         self).OnGetItemBackgroundColour(indices)

    def OnGetItemImage(self, indices, which):
        # Return the right icon depending on whether the item has children.
        if which in [wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal, wx.TreeItemIcon_Selected]:
            if self.model.GetChildrenCount(indices):
                return 0
            else:
                return 2
        else:
            return 1

    def OnDrop(self, dropTarget, dragItem):
        dropIndex = self.GetIndexOfItem(dropTarget)
        dropText = self.model.GetText(dropIndex)
        dragIndex = self.GetIndexOfItem(dragItem)
        dragText = self.model.GetText(dragIndex)

        self.model.MoveItem(dragIndex, dropIndex)
        self.GetParent().RefreshItems()


class VirtualTreeCtrl(DemoTreeMixin, wx.TreeCtrl):
    pass


class VirtualTreeListCtrl(DemoTreeMixin, wx.gizmos.TreeListCtrl):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['style'] = wx.TR_DEFAULT_STYLE | wx.TR_FULL_ROW_HIGHLIGHT
        super(VirtualTreeListCtrl, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.AddColumn('Column 0')
        self.AddColumn('Column 1')
        for art in wx.ART_TIP, wx.ART_WARNING:
            self.imageList.Add(wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(art, wx.ART_OTHER, 
                                                        (16, 16)))

    def OnGetItemText(self, indices, column=0):
        # Return a different label depending on column.
        return '%s, column %d'%\
            (super(VirtualTreeListCtrl, self).OnGetItemText(indices), column)

    def OnGetItemImage(self, indices, which, column=0):
        # Also change the image of the other columns when the item has 
        # children.
        if column == 0:
            return super(VirtualTreeListCtrl, self).OnGetItemImage(indices, 
                                                                   which)
        elif self.OnGetChildrenCount(indices):
            return 4
        else:
            return 3


class VirtualCustomTreeCtrl(DemoTreeMixin, 
                            wx.lib.customtreectrl.CustomTreeCtrl):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.checked = {}
        kwargs['style'] = wx.TR_HIDE_ROOT | \
            wx.TR_HAS_BUTTONS | wx.TR_FULL_ROW_HIGHLIGHT
        super(VirtualCustomTreeCtrl, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.Bind(wx.lib.customtreectrl.EVT_TREE_ITEM_CHECKED,
                  self.OnItemChecked)

    def OnGetItemType(self, indices):
        if len(indices) == 1:
            return 1
        elif len(indices) == 2:
            return 2
        else:
            return 0

    def OnGetItemChecked(self, indices):
        return self.checked.get(indices, False)

    def OnItemChecked(self, event):
        item = event.GetItem()
        itemIndex = self.GetIndexOfItem(item)
        if self.GetItemType(item) == 2: 
            # It's a radio item; reset other items on the same level
            for nr in range(self.GetChildrenCount(self.GetItemParent(item))):
                self.checked[itemIndex[:-1]+(nr,)] = False
        self.checked[itemIndex] = True



class TreeNotebook(wx.Notebook):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        treemodel = kwargs.pop('treemodel')
        super(TreeNotebook, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.trees = []
        for class_, title in [(VirtualTreeCtrl, 'TreeCtrl'),
                              (VirtualTreeListCtrl, 'TreeListCtrl'),
                              (VirtualCustomTreeCtrl, 'CustomTreeCtrl')]:
            tree = class_(self, treemodel=treemodel)
            self.trees.append(tree)
            self.AddPage(tree, title)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED, self.OnPageChanged)

    def OnPageChanged(self, event):
        oldTree = self.GetPage(event.OldSelection)
        newTree = self.GetPage(event.Selection)
        newTree.RefreshItems()
        newTree.SetExpansionState(oldTree.GetExpansionState())
        event.Skip()

    def GetIndicesOfSelectedItems(self):
        tree = self.trees[self.GetSelection()]
        if tree.GetSelections():
            return [tree.GetIndexOfItem(item) for item in tree.GetSelections()]
        else:
            return [()]

    def RefreshItems(self):
        tree = self.trees[self.GetSelection()]
        tree.RefreshItems()
        tree.UnselectAll()


class TestPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.treemodel = TreeModel()
        self.CreateControls()
        self.LayoutControls()

    def CreateControls(self):
        self.notebook = TreeNotebook(self, treemodel=self.treemodel) 
        self.label = wx.StaticText(self, label='Number of children: ')
        self.childrenCountCtrl = wx.SpinCtrl(self, value='0', max=10000)
        self.button = wx.Button(self, label='Update children')
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnEnter)

    def LayoutControls(self):
        hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        options = dict(flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, border=2)
        hSizer.Add(self.label, **options)
        hSizer.Add(self.childrenCountCtrl, 2, **options)
        hSizer.Add(self.button, **options)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.notebook, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(hSizer, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnEnter(self, event):
        indicesList = self.notebook.GetIndicesOfSelectedItems()
        newChildrenCount = self.childrenCountCtrl.GetValue()
        for indices in indicesList:
            text = self.treemodel.GetText(indices)
            oldChildrenCount = self.treemodel.GetChildrenCount(indices)
#             self.log.write('%s %s now has %d children (was %d)'%(text, indices,
#                 newChildrenCount, oldChildrenCount))
            self.treemodel.SetChildrenCount(indices, newChildrenCount)
        self.notebook.RefreshItems()

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Test")
        panel = TestPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I have commented all the logs and made appropriate changes but now I get a different problem..I have given the new code above..Error---TypeError: in method 'new_Notebook', expected argument 1 of type 'wxWindow *'